Can I use the OZ Ownable contract with a multisig wallet if I want some functions to require varying voting thresholds?
Some functions like the mint() will require unanimous approval from contract owners, while others will only require simple majority of contract owners.  I want to use Safe Wallet or some other multisig wallet together with the simple OZ Ownable contract, but I am not sure how I can achieve this functionality.
One option is to use multisig threshold for all simple majority functions and use a mapping with all added owners for the unanimous votes.  However, it seems like this is almost the same as putting the multisig logic in the contract fully.
Has anyone come across a similar issue?

I think the easiest would be to add a custom Ownable that supports two types (or more) of owners. Or probably better with Role based access.
The controlling addresses would then be different multisigs, with different configurations.

I was thinking to just use two different multisig wallets with different voting thresholds, but it would be potentially annoying for the users rather than voting from one wallet.  I dont think Roles are super applicable because it would just be one address of each type, though.

I meant to use two roles and each role has a different multisig address assigned. But, figure out what works best for you
